# How to merge the content of multiple subdirectories into another directory where destination contains the same directory name using a mount / union?

Tags: filesystems, mount, directory, merge

In the example below, `exdir` is a directory containing many subdirectories. The contents of each subdirectory, which are directories themselves, should be merged with `/su/destdir`, which already contain directories of the same names.

The end result, for example, should be a filesystem where `/su/destdir/a` contains the files and directories already in `/su/destdir/a`, and additionally the files and directories in `/home/user/exdir/412/a`, `/home/user/exdir/754/a`, and finally `/home/user/exdir/612/a`.

Any changes made in `/home/user/exdir/*` would thus effect any executable that reads the directory `/su/destdir` when this union is active. If not active, the `/su/destdir` directory should appear unchanged.

```
/home/user/exdir/412
└── a

/home/user/exdir/754
├── a
└── b

/home/user/exdir/523
└── c

/home/user/exdir/612
├── a
├── d
├── f
├── c
└── e

/su/destdir
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
├── e
├── f
├── g
├── h
├── j
└── k
```